# Bootstrap Table set search text on page change

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-table

I have a custom search. When the button is clicked, 
i'm retrieving the search text using:

```
$('.fixed-table-toolbar').find('.search > :input').val()
```

I'm then using the refresh event to post back to my controller:

```
$table.bootstrapTable('refresh', {
url: '@Url.Action("Action", "ControllerName")',
query: { searchText: searchValue }
});
```

I also have paging, so if the search results send back many results i need to page through those results with the same searchText but when it posts back to controller on page change then the searchText value is null. I tried using the :   $table.on('page-change.bs.table') event and then have the refresh event like the one posted above but obviously that posts back twice to the controller, on the first call searchText is null and on the second it has the value set. How can i make the searchText value persist when paging ?

Thanks

Comment: it would be null, use ajax. why use paging anyway if you are just pulling all the results anyway; paging is for when you are pulling small sets of data at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resetSearch` method to solve your problem, example [here](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/resetSearch.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can set search text while initializing the table. 
For static search use this:

```
data-search-text="your hard coded search content"
```

For dynamic search use this:

```
var searchText = 'Test search content';
$('#tableId').bootstrapTable({
        searchText: searchText,
 });
```

NOTE: Remember to use data-search="true" for the table (By default it is false).